# rails acts_as_list specific to user and date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

I'd like to use acts_as_list in my stock market application but the ordering position should be specific to the user, the ticker and date.

```
acts_as_list scope: [:user_id, :ticker, :market_date]
```

So, when ordering is performed, it should look at the combination of these 3 fields to determine which records should be reordered, rather than reordering all trades or all of a user's (all-time) trades. Can this be done and am I going about it in the right way?